# Insert records into Access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oledb

I would like to insert variables in access, but Im getting this error message:  OleDBExeception was unhandled; No value given for one or more required parameters.   Can anyone tell me where the mistake is?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strSurname, strName As String
    strSurname = Me.TextBox1.Text
    strName = Me.TextBox2.Text

    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim ConString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= Dbtry.accdb ; Persist Security Info=True"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim sqlQry As String

    sqlQry = "INSERT INTO BookingFly (ID,Client_Name, Client_Surname) VALUES(1,strSurname, strName)"

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myConnection)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be ..

```
sqlQry = "INSERT INTO BookingFly (ID,Client_Name, Client_Surname) VALUES(1, '" & strSurname & "','" & strName "')"
```

Better you use parameter .. for your data safety ..

Comment: @user2802425 .. please make a green tick below downvote sign (if this helped you) ..